# What does it take to become a professional chess player?

Tags: chessboards

I need to know how start to become a professional chess player so that I can participate in tournaments.

I first tried to find someone who knows how to play, but didn't find anyone. 
So I started looking through the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the life of a professional GM with ELO around 2500?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19433/how-is-the-life-of-a-professional-gm-with-elo-around-2500)

Comment: How good are you at the moment? And how old?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to be a professional to participate in a tournament, you just have to sign up for the tournament (as long as it's not by invitation only or has minimum rating requirements). You may need to register with your national chess federation first.

As for becoming a professional, I'm not one but I guess the old "practice, practice, practice!" rule is a start. Of course, it also helps to start young, have talent and a good mentor.

Answer (score 5):

To become a professional player who makes a living from tournaments, you really need a GM+ level. Even as a GM, you might find yourself struggling for your bills.

Raise your FIDE to 2500, come back then we talk.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably need to be [2600+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_rating_system#Elo_rating_system) and play a lot of tournaments in order to make a living, and don't expect to get rich. I'm from the Netherlands though, and the prize pool in most tournaments isn't as high as in the US for example.

I know several strong grandmasters who play poker because you can earn a lot more. Even [Hikaru Nakamura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikaru_Nakamura) used to play poker a lot (though I'm not sure if money was the main reason there).

If you want to make a living in chess, you need to either be really good, or do coaching on the side.